# call constructor of a derived class after a dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, polymorphism, factory

I'm trying to implement a factory of characters but I can't understand how to create a generic shared_ptr to the virtual base class and then cast it to a derived class with arguments in the constructor. 
In my example, my virtual base class can't take arguments in the constructor, but I need them in the constructor of the derived class.

```
std::shared_ptr<Character> CharacterFactory::createCharacter(Character::Type type, Character::SubType subtype, const TextureHolder &textures, sf::Vector2u windowSize) {

    std::shared_ptr<Character> character;

    if ( type == Character::enemy ) {
        std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Enemy>(character)(subType, textures, windowSize);

    } else if(type == Character::player) {
        //cast to player ...
    }

    return character;
```

Probably it's a design problem and I can't solve it. I can't use raw pointers, if I could I think that

```
character = new Enemy(...);
```

would have worked. All examples I have found for casting use default constructors.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `std::make_shared<Enemy>(...)`

Comment: Constructors cannot be called explicitly. They are nameless, there address cannot be taken and the are not functions that can be called. They may only ever be called implicitly by the process of creating a new object. Your construct seems like it would try to call `operator()` instead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I think you meant that there is no special syntax for calling constructors. They can most certainly be called explicitly. It's only for the cases of default construction and conversion that they can be called implicitly. However, I recall having a years long discussion about that with James Kanze. He wasn't convinced until I coughed up some quotes of Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf There may be a misunderstanding of here. I didn't mean to refer to implicit constructor calls as those used in implicit conversions. I mean those calls that are generated by creating a new instance. I also don't consider constructing an object to be an explicit call to the constructor (even though a constructor will be called). My comment was meant to say that there is no way to call a constructor as you would a function. In other words, creating an object is distinct from calling an object's constructor.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Well, `T()` calls the `T` default constructor, producing a `T` object. That's "like a function" to me. It's a function, that's called, and it looks like a function call (even though syntactically I think it's a type conversion expression, which doesn't make sense semantically, but). Summing up, it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, and waddles like a duck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be casting here.  In your if-else chain what you do is create a shared pointer to the appropriate type and then return that `shared_ptr`.  It will automatically get converted to a `std::shared_ptr<Character>` just like you get when you have

```
Character * character = new Enemy(...);
```

That means your function should look something like

```
std::shared_ptr<Character> CharacterFactory::createCharacter(Character::Type type, Character::SubType subtype, const TextureHolder &textures, sf::Vector2u windowSize) {    
    if ( type == Character::enemy ) {
        return std::make_shared<Enemy>(subType, textures, windowSize);
    } else if(type == Character::player) {
        return std::make_shared<Player>(subType, textures, windowSize);
    } 
    return {}; // return null on bad type
}
```

---

We can apply a few tweeks to the above to make it more performant and to not just silently return a null pointer if the factory is passed a bad `type`.  To do that we will use a `std::unique_ptr` and throw an exception if we get a bad `type`.  `std_unique_ptr` can be converted to a `std::shared_ptr` so this lets your factory work with both types of smart pointers by default.  That gives us

```
std::unique_ptr<Character> CharacterFactory::createCharacter(Character::Type type, Character::SubType subtype, const TextureHolder &textures, sf::Vector2u windowSize) {    
    if ( type == Character::enemy ) {
        return std::make_unique<Enemy>(subType, textures, windowSize);
    } else if(type == Character::player) {
        return std::make_unique<Player>(subType, textures, windowSize);
    } 
    throw std::runtime_error("bad type passed to factory");
}
```